# Getting unique tuples from a list

Tags: python, python-2.7, set, unique

I have a list of tuples whose elements are like this:

```
aa = [('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd'), ('b', 'a')]
```

I want to treat `('a', 'b') and ('b', 'a')` as the same group and want to extract only unique tuples. So the output should be like this:

```
[('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd')]
```

How can I achieve this efficiently as my list consists of millions of such tuples?

Comment: You can use `set` and `frozenset`, e.g. `{frozenset(x) for x in aa}`

Comment: So which of the two would need to be selected? Does order matter?

Comment: No order doesn't matter

Comment: Does the order have to be preserved? Would `[('c', 'd'), ('a', 'b')]` or `[('b', 'a'), ('c', 'd')]` be valid outputs?

Comment: You can either keep first instance or the last instance. The order isn't a big deal but the uniqueness of the group is

Comment: So if input is `[('a', 'b')]`, output `[('b', 'a')]` is ok?

Comment: Yeap, it's okay

Comment: @mlRocks: why are those objects tuples then? You may want to make the sets (`frozenset` or `set`, immutable or mutable) to begin with.

Comment: You can put the groups in a list if you want to. The only objective is that the program should output unique pairs, no matter how you represent them internally

Comment: Can there be tuples where both values are the same, e.g., `('a', 'a')`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Convert to a `frozenset`, hash, and retrieve:

```
In [193]: map(tuple, set(map(frozenset, aa))) # python2
Out[193]: [('d', 'c'), ('a', 'b')]
```

Here's a slightly more readable version with a list comprehension:

```
In [194]: [tuple(x) for x in set(map(frozenset, aa))]
Out[194]: [('d', 'c'), ('a', 'b')]
```

---

Do note that, for your particular use case, a list of tuples isn't the best choice of data structure. Consider storing your data as a set to begin with?

```
In [477]: set(map(frozenset, aa))
Out[477]: {frozenset({'a', 'b'}), frozenset({'c', 'd'})}
```

Comment: Set of tuples then?

Comment: @mlRocks Might be a problem considering tuples are ordered and hashable. Maybe a set of frozensets to begin with.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Will keep that in mind

Answer (score 0):

Given order doesn't matter just convert to `set` and `frozenset`, this seems like a better data structure fit than `list` and `tuple`, e.g.:

```
>>> {frozenset(x) for x in aa}
{frozenset({'c', 'd'}), frozenset({'a', 'b'})}
```